# Parasoft c++ test link unit test error

Tags: c++, unit-testing, parasoft

My project can build & link successfully, and there is no compile error about unit test.

The error information only "Test execution: error linking test executable for Test unit for selected sources."

So, anyone can give some suggestion? Thanks.

I use VS2005, and parasoft c++ test for VS 9.1.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you have any questions about Parasoft products, I suggest emailing their support team at support@parasoft.com, you could also call them toll free at (888) 305-0041.

In addition you will probably get your question answered faster if you post this on their forum. link provided below.

http://forums.parasoft.com/

Comment: Welcome on SO. This is not really an answer to the question but reads rather like an advertisement. Why not try to solve OPs problem and drop the link? Makes a much better impression.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the output window of VS, there are more information about the link error, then i can fix it.